# Servlet - File location

Tags: servlets, location

I am working with a servlet in Eclipse (Dynamic Web Project) . I have placed some image file in Web Content Folder with a sub-folder pics. Now there are images like pic1.jpg , etc.

```
 BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File(location)));
```

What location should i give in order to retrieve these files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
ServletContext ctx=getServletContext();
InputStream in = ctx.getResourceAsStream("/pics/pic1.jpg");
```

`getResourceAsStream()` requires you to start with a `"/"` which represents the root of the web app.